# Criar a mesma função em php

Tags: php, javascript, array

Tenho a seguinte função em `javaScript`:

```js
function teste(ctrl) {
  var str = ctrl.value;
  var str = str.split(" ");

  if (str.every(isBigEnough) && str.length >= 2) {
    alert(true);
  } else {
    alert(false);
  }
}

function isBigEnough(element, index, array) {
    return element.length > 1;
}
```

```html
<input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome completo" required onchange="teste(this)">
```

Quero replica-la em `php` para ter essa validação também no `back-end`
Existe uma função em php similar, o `array_walk` só que não estou conseguindo ainda.
Seria algo do tipo:

```
function isBigEnough($item, $key) {
    return strlen($item) >= 2;
}

function validaNome($value) {
    var $str = $value;
    var $str = explode(" ",$value);

    if (array_walk($str, 'isBigEnough') && count($str) >= 2) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: precisa ser similar a técnica da versão javascript?

Comment: precisa executar a mesma ação, em `javascript` eu explodo a `string` e verifico o tamanho de cada elemento dela, se cada elemento for maior que 2 ok, senão não passa, queria evitar o `foreach`, mas se for o caminho menos sofrível, ok

Comment: ok, o que importa é o resultado final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o `array_map` para aplicar uma função em cada elemento do array, assim você irá verificar a quantidade caracteres em cada elemento.

```
<?php 

    function isBigEnough($item){

        if(strlen($item) > 2){

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }


    function validaNome($nome){

        $arrayNome = explode(" ", $nome);

        if(in_array(false, array_map("isBigEnough", $arrayNome))){

            echo "Não é válido!";

        } else {

            echo "ok!";

        }

    }

    validaNome("Marcelo Bonifazio");


?>
```

Outros programadores também gostam evitar uso de loops explícitos. O porque, eu não sei, pois os loops geralmente são 2x mais rápidos e menos complicados para utilizar que estes tipos de códigos. Se você puder comentar depois, só por curiosidade mesmo, eu agradeço. =)

Mas está ai. Abraço!

Comment: A ideia não é fugir de loop, é aplicar a mesma função logica de verificação em cada elemento, estou somente replicando as mesmas funções que criei em front-end em back-end, não importa qual o método utilizado, loop, recursividade, passada de parâmetro e por ai vai :)

Comment: Irei testa-la :D

Comment: Entendi. Fiz alterações... Obrigado!